# Bash script find directories with modified files in it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

For usage within a backup script I'm looking for a way to find all folders which have been modified since a certain time. I got to this:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1 -type d
```

Unfortunately, this does not return any results, since the directories itself have not been modified, only the contents within some of the directories. The complete script is now:

```
repodir=/somepath
backupdir=/someotherpath

find . -mtime -1 -type d -maxdepth 1|while read repo; do
  svnadmin dump -q $repodir/$repo | bzip2 -9 > $backupdir/$repo-`date +%F`.dump.bz2
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -mtime -1 | sed 's,^\./,,;s,/.*$,,' | sort -u | \
while read repo; do
   svnadmin dump -q $repodir/$repo | bzip2 -9 > $backupdir/$repo-`date +%F`.dump.bz2
done
```

It searches for files in subdirectories which have changed, then strips off all but the first directory component from the path, and uses `sort -u` to remove duplicates. Note that it also strips off the initial `./` from the results, but it looks like you don't really want/need that part anyway.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking in that direction as well, but couldn't get the sed part right. This works perfect!